# If variable is not set, wait for variable to be set

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, asynchronous, delegates

I have 2 delegate methods that are being called by notifications from a 3rd party library.

Method 1:
`mediaContentWasUpdated()`

Method 2:
`adMediaDidBeginPlaying()`

In Method 1, a key variable (`adDuration`) is set from a parameter that is passed in with the notification. As far as I can see this is the only place to get this information.

In Method 2, we check the `adDuration` and if it is greater than 0 then we update the UI to reflect that we are in fact play an ad.

A bug has appeared where sometimes these two methods are called in the wrong order. Meaning the `adDuration` is not set and Method 2 thinks there is no ad media to be played and does not update the UI accordingly.

My current attempt at a solution is to make `adDuration` optional and use an NSCondition to cause Method 2 to wait for Method 1 to set `adDuration` and then proceed.

```
var adDuration : Double?
let condition = NSCondition()

func mediaContentWasUpdated(notification: NSNotificiation) {
    condition.lock()

    if(notificationHasAdDurationInfo(notification)) {
        self.adDuration = getAdDuration(notification)
        condition.signal()
    }

    condition.unlock()
}

func adMediaDidBeginPlaying(notification: NSNotification) {
    condition.lock()

    while adDuration == nil {
        condition.wait()
    }

    if adDuration! > Double(0) {
        updateUIForAd()
    }

    condition.unlock()
}
```

This is my first time trying something like this and I worry I am doing something wrong. I also have some concerns about locking and unlocking threads needlessly (which would happen in a well timed run, or if there were no ad content to be played).

Outside factors are hindering my ability to test and I wanted to get some input to see if I am heading in the right direction while I wait for those issues to be resolved.

Comment: Why not just call the second method yourself after getting the `adDuration` in the first method.

Comment: @SanthoshR The second method is also a notification delegate method. It should only be called if there is an ad about to play.

Comment: I know but if you get `adDuration` greater than zero in the first method then it means there is an ad, and you can then call the second method with a fake notification.

Comment: `adDuration` could also mean mid-roll ads are available.
The code is pretty simplified, Method 2 makes use of info sent down with its `notification` object.

Comment: ah so you need info in the `notification` of second method also. That makes sense.

Comment: Additional complexity doesn't really matter.  If method 2 depends on certain conditions, you should refactor the code so that it's only called after those conditions are met; pass the notification content if necessary.

Comment: Why not have a Boolean property that is set to `true` when `adMediaDidBeginPlaying` is called.  Then in both delegate call your "updateUI" function; if duration is nil or the flag is false, have the updateUI function return immediately. Once you have a duration and a flag, update the UI and clear the flag, ready for next time. This way it doesn't matter in which order the delegate methods are called

Comment: Another possibility is to use Swift's `didset` and then request whatever else you need for processing from some data source.

Comment: @Paulw11 Your solution is my next attempt if this one does not work. I feel like NSConditions were made for this sort of scenario. Adding them does not change the code significantly so I see them as the ideal solution.
If I could get them to work, that is.

Comment: @Conor you can set value of adDuration Double(0) after calling  updateUIForAd() method. I hope its helps you.

Comment: The big risk with an NSCondition is a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

Your discussion of NSCondition got me on the same track with you, and I built two or three solutions using DispatchGroup (which is the better tool for this), but they always had little corner cases that could behave badly, and didn't really capture the intent.

(If you're interested in the DispatchGroup solutions, they're of the form: call `.enter()` in `init`, call `.leave()` when the duration comes in, call `notify()` when the playing starts. It works fine, but it introduces corner cases that can crash, just like `NSCondition`.)

Getting back to the real intent:

> Update the UI when the duration is known and the ad has started playing.

There's no concurrency going on here. So pulling out GCD is not just overkill; it actually makes things worse because it introduces lots of complicated corner cases.

So I thought about how I'd have solved this back before GCD. And the answer is obvious: just check if you have the data you want, and then do the thing. (Reading through the comments, I see Paulw11 pointed this out as well.)

Personally I like to pull this kind of thing into its own type to make things more self-contained. I hate some of the names here, but the idea should be clear:

```
class AdPlayer {
    private var readyToPlay = false
    private var duration: Double = 0.0
    private let completion: (Double) -> Void

    func setDuration(from notification: Notification) {
        if(notificationHasAdDurationInfo(notification)) {
            duration = getAdDuration(notification)
        }
        playIfReady()
    }

    func play() {
        readyToPlay = true
        playIfReady()
    }

    private func playIfReady() {
        if duration > 0 && readyToPlay {
            completion(duration)
        }
    }

    init(completion: @escaping (Double) -> Void) {
        self.completion = completion
    }
}
```

When you set each thing, see if you're ready to update, and if so, update. I've gotten rid of the optional as well, since I believe the intent is "0 duration is always wrong." But you could use an Optional so you could detect actually receiving a 0 from the notification.

With that, you just set up a player property:

```
player = AdPlayer(completion: updateUIForAd)
```

(Note that the above might be creating a retain loop, depending on what `updateUIForAd` is; you may need a `[weak self]` closure or the like here.)

And then update it as needed:

```
func mediaContentWasUpdated(notification: NSNotificiation) {
    player.setDuration(from: notification)
}

func adMediaDidBeginPlaying(notification: NSNotification) {
    player.play()
}
```

A big advantage of creating the `AdPlayer` type is that it's easy to reset the system when the ad is done (or if something goes wrong). Just throw away the whole object and create another one.